# how to select data with syntax sql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
id. goods             qty 
1    ABC susu ds       1
2    ABC susu gt       1
3    Kapal api moca    1  
4    kapal api mix     1
```

how to display with sql syntax be ..

```
id      goods                 qty
1       ABC susu              2
2       Kapal api             2
```

because there is a  duplicate of ABC susu and kapal api then the amount is added.

Help me please,

Comment: Please take a few moments and fix your formatting.

Comment: ...And to create a [mcve]

Comment: What SQL did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new id base on the grouping (@id) then I get substring of goods without the last word. I also used uppercase because I notice that the first letter of 3rd row is not the same with last row. Then did a sum of the qty.

```
select @id:=@id+1 as id, 
substr(goods,1,length(goods)-locate(' ', reverse(goods))) as goods,
sum(qty) as qty
from yourTable
inner join (select @id:=0) s
group by ucase(substr(goods,1,length(goods)-locate(' ', reverse(goods))))
```

See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f70b381/17

```
Result:
id  goods      qty
1   ABC susu    2
2   Kapal api   2
```